# Installing Windows 7 on an HP Stream 11

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, installation

I am in the process of installing Windows 7 on an HP laptop (Stream 11-y010wm).

I have worked past the usual problems of installation, I have a bootable win7 install usb with usb drivers included. Normally this is enough, however this specific laptop has another curveball. Instead of a normal hdd or ssd this laptop uses something called an eMMC, which is like an ssd only is soldered onto the motherboard and is not listed as PCI or SATA hardware.

I have used windows PE to boot and look at the system information to try to find vendor and device ids to get a clue on what I'm dealing with but as I said before, it is not listed from what I can tell. And of course hp doesn't actually supply drivers for this component, and even if they did they would be Win10 exclusively.

I understand that Windows 7 is not meant to be ran on this laptop but I want to do it anyways.

TLDR:

What I need is information, or preferably driver files, for the eMMC on an HP Stream 11-y010wm. If additional information is required I will supply it as soon as possible.

Comment: Only the manufacturer or a very dedicated PC hardware enthusiast would be able to create the firmware that you need.  If it hasn't been created already, and it sounds like it hasn't, it has to be made at the cost of many engineer hours.

Answer (score 0):

After much investigation, I found drivers that are supposed to be compatible with the hardware in this computer, and are windows 7 drivers. I knew that there had to be windows 7 drivers for this computer because the actual hardware is too old for there not to be. However after integrating these drivers into the win7 installer it still cannot see the drive. I was finally able to gain access to the win10 partition and boot it, and device manager told me that the driver used for this drive is disk.sys, I can only assume that the hardware has been tweaked so that only this newer driver can operate it, barring a win7 install.